# Error in trying to Upload 3 images

Tags: php, syntax-error

Hello i'm new in PHP and i'm trying to upload 3 images and i got an error
Please don't downgrade me i'm just learning and trying to make a simple system. Thank you

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\epushmoyan\customer\connect.php on line 17
```

Here's my code :

```
function addpost($a,$b,$c,$d,$name,$type,$size,$tmp_name,$error,$name1,$type1,$size1,$tmp_name1,$error1,$name2,$type2,$size2,$tmp_name2,$error2,$e)
{
$img = 'thumbnails/products/'.$name.$name1.$name2

mysql_query("INSERT post(p_name,p_contact,p_email,image,image1,image2,p_address,dateadded) values ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$img','$e',NOW())");

if ($error > 0)
{
die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
}
else
{
if($size> 10000000000) //conditions for the file
{
die("Format is not allowed or file size is too big!");
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$tmp_name1,$tmp_name2,"thumbnails/products/".$name.$name1,$name2);
} 
}
```

Comment: "I get an error" isn't enough info to be able to offer suggestions from. Can you be more specific of the issues you face and what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `;`:

```
$img = 'thumbnails/products/'.$name.$name1.$name2
                                                 ^--- here
mysql_query
```

Voting to close, since it's a simple typo.

Comment: Why answer if you're voting to close? Out of interest

Comment: to close the whole question. simple typos are not a valid question. But it's also not fair to simply cut off the OP without giving them an answer.

Comment: hello, when i close it. i got this error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\epushmoyan\customer\connect.php on line 38 it is the last line. just the closing " ?> "

Answer (score 0):

Missing ; in

```
$img = 'thumbnails/products/'.$name.$name1.$name2
```